# removing baseline signal using fourier transforms

Tags: numpy, signal-processing, fft

I have timeseries data for many terms an example of which is below:

```
term1 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.2384935833581433e-06, 3.938767914008819e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 1.1961851263949013e-06, 0.0, 2.278384397623645e-06, 1.100158422812885e-06, 0.0, 1.095521835393462e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 1.6933152148605343e-06, 0.0, 8.460737945563612e-07, 8.949410770794851e-07, 0.0, 2.8698467119209605e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.9163008188985015e-06, 2.2244961516216576e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 1.9407903674692482e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.514657329616274e-07, 1.94463053478312e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0373216961518047e-06, 1.8835690620014428e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.707946148081127e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 1.6121985390256838e-06, 1.9547361301697883e-06, 0.0, 2.2876018840689116e-06, 2.208826914114183e-06, 1.9640500282823203e-06, 0.0, 2.6234669115235785e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.986207773222741e-06, 1.049193537387487e-06, 1.090723073046815e-06, 0.0, 1.0257546476943088e-06, 9.179053033814713e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.335621182897889e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.1267500494469387e-06, 2.215050381320923e-06, 2.163720040591388e-06, 1.937729136470388e-06, 1.6037643556956889e-06, 1.313906783569333e-06, 0.0, 1.0064645216223805e-06, 1.876346865234201e-06, 9.504447606257348e-07, 2.017974095266539e-06, 0.0, 2.120782823355757e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.216394491176685e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0401357169083422e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0089962853658684e-06, 1.8249773702806084e-06, 0.0, 1.2890950295073852e-06, 5.42812725267281e-06, 1.9185480428411778e-06, 2.6955316172381044e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0070239923466176e-06, 0.0, 1.021152145542773e-06, 9.919749228739498e-07, 1.9293082175989564e-06, 9.802489636317832e-07, 1.0483850676418046e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.9369409504181854e-06, 0.0, 4.619620451983665e-06, 0.0, 6.0795324434248845e-06, 0.0, 1.5312669396405198e-06, 1.2797051559320733e-06, 1.1002903666277531e-06, 0.0, 1.0054768323055684e-06, 2.060260561153169e-06, 1.0898719291496056e-06, 3.4605907920600203e-06, 3.3500051925080486e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.5521496510980315e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.01862187836765e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.849817053093449e-06, 6.5552277941658475e-06, 1.985771944021089e-06, 1.010233667047188e-06, 9.802307070992228e-07, 5.605931075077432e-06, 3.651067480854715e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 2.9476960807432912e-06, 1.834478659509754e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.3801712394749917e-06, 0.0, 2.2884970981856794e-06, 1.02014792144861e-06, 2.906143199237428e-06, 9.807873564740302e-07, 0.0, 2.106593638087213e-06, 3.0329622335542676e-06, 2.9093758515985565e-06, 0.0, 2.12762335960239e-06, 9.614820669172289e-07, 9.264114341404848e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 9.073611487918033e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0360958532021484e-06, 0.0, 4.553288270957079e-06, 2.0712553257152562e-06, 3.292603824030081e-06, 2.690786880261329e-06, 2.301011409565074e-06, 2.029661472762958e-06, 0.0, 9.657114492818003e-07, 9.948942029504583e-07, 1.028682761437152e-06, 2.0694207898151387e-06, 3.845369982272845e-06, 9.048250701691842e-07, 1.7726379156614332e-06, 0.0, 9.238711680133629e-07, 9.231112912203808e-07, 9.422814896339613e-07, 0.0, 1.2123519263665934e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 2.1675188628329036e-06, 0.0, 4.498718989767663e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 2.650273839544471e-06, 1.1954029583832415e-06, 4.180999656112778e-06, 1.9036523473937095e-06, 9.75877289286136e-07, 0.0, 2.093618232902467e-06, 1.032899928523325e-06, 0.0, 4.473312219299659e-06, 8.762705923589204e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 1.792797436299666e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 1.1974513445582422e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.1404264054329915e-06, 3.061324451410658e-06, 9.84829683554526e-07, 2.932895354293759e-06, 2.0897069394988045e-06, 0.0, 2.128187093183736e-06, 0.0, 4.686861415132188e-06, 6.37755683086446e-06, 1.8420463661490824e-06, 2.8347403094402523e-06, 1.9033842171380715e-06, 6.909144746582441e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 1.5479612576256442e-06, 5.621978186724636e-06, 2.087185930697078e-06, 1.3168406359462377e-05, 1.9676130885622652e-05, 1.9988766313331908e-05, 3.1801079228204546e-05, 3.322824899588385e-05, 2.0358501231090545e-05, 1.2383952049337664e-05, 1.8052256532066507e-05, 7.770543617518302e-06, 9.226179797741636e-06, 4.400430362089412e-06, 4.333084180992927e-06, 7.477274426653279e-06, 3.0526428255261993e-06, 4.952368123389242e-06, 1.2578584707962998e-05, 0.0, 2.121750274236223e-06, 0.0, 2.38940918273843e-06, 0.0, 1.5693511988273807e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 4.520448247648237e-06, 4.0303440122522456e-05, 2.8660979509446863e-05, 2.4793768971660722e-05, 3.957070185234852e-05, 2.64488881248099e-05, 6.428381095168035e-05, 5.6557662521419976e-05, 6.855540059858658e-05, 7.079288025889968e-05, 7.135683422742382e-05, 5.5663480860112103e-05, 8.088436527379357e-05, 7.142268494354861e-05, 8.243171356847987e-05, 7.658173644233611e-05, 5.4275733753644613e-05, 2.7329513031804995e-05, 1.8666856995404658e-05, 2.5061514626811264e-05, 9.707359513272993e-06, 2.233654188450612e-05, 2.0577084330035857e-05, 6.037067595033506e-05, 5.358585847760433e-05, 6.353114888415205e-05, 4.913406130358561e-05, 6.253876100291326e-05, 5.783647108547192e-05, 5.29265883017118e-05, 4.295770587763158e-05, 0.00012513639867455526, 0.0001264425725280477, 0.00010075697417828198, 7.700585441944497e-05, 6.390017630639553e-05, 6.862379380485504e-05, 8.118867124374998e-05, 8.928305705187346e-05, 8.923668314113125e-05, 5.0862818355003976e-05, 2.5192448399293734e-05, 1.9491995287268695e-05, 1.1397180337584482e-05, 1.8548131739430545e-05, 2.8274146120787152e-05, 2.9861740143137274e-05, 5.749201435920551e-05, 8.676081065218611e-05, 0.00011692016691003383, 6.18107213073443e-05, 8.31986307882476e-05, 5.661490072734421e-05, 6.637785526376392e-05, 6.189842468509176e-05, 5.077848495281155e-05, 3.7630726455798414e-05, 6.325167842846687e-05, 7.447442335517917e-05, 7.881778491014126e-05, 8.347575938861497e-05, 6.553610066345062e-05, 6.209221186256924e-05, 4.671174184109858e-05, 4.583301504850661e-05, 2.9423292949863758e-05, 1.9969520206001368e-05, 1.3386836054765546e-05, 1.0233804045678584e-05, 2.3371876153986385e-05, 3.701784260013326e-05, 2.6804842191646374e-05, 3.729558727386808e-05, 7.011179438698544e-05, 4.616049584765358e-05, 6.019787395273405e-05, 8.312188292939014e-05, 6.281596430043117e-05, 6.370630077282333e-05, 6.169767733530766e-05, 6.099512039036877e-05, 7.192322709245217e-05, 6.727547574464268e-05, 4.891125624919348e-05, 8.775231227342841e-05, 9.349358010749929e-05, 4.85363097385816e-05, 4.475820776946539e-05, 1.9528637281926147e-05, 1.5243002033035396e-05, 1.4322461630125293e-05, 1.0492122514416176e-05, 1.1956759574674148e-05, 1.5232250274180506e-05, 3.394641638997643e-05, 2.6115894879792267e-05, 4.868559048521277e-05, 5.612535494090208e-05, 3.269545148571978e-05, 4.967751016319062e-05, 4.8382804751191425e-05, 5.1860846075881435e-05, 4.4034258653232213e-05, 5.362193446127224e-05, 6.213052893181175e-05, 8.561827093901839e-05, 5.877682625663455e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 7.105805443046969e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 2.31393994554528e-05, 7.05044594070575e-06, 2.21491300929156e-05, 4.926848615186025e-06, 1.0752514744385843e-05, 1.4745260873155369e-05, 1.976297604068538e-05, 3.094705732168692e-05, 5.068338091939653e-05, 2.655137469742496e-05, 3.0142790705685793e-05, 3.89279249469607e-05, 6.264176821226988e-05, 3.598536226187379e-05, 4.430195278344506e-05, 2.7501831818440764e-05, 1.7243328268903956e-05, 1.2049184772240285e-05, 2.1016880758625327e-05, 3.411070201956675e-05, 3.1893789428697184e-05, 1.8509911029027654e-05, 3.920735117199027e-05, 3.700840501998454e-05, 8.529330234343347e-06, 1.1007881643256571e-05, 4.661265813344272e-06, 7.306007242688513e-06, 2.6772256446090046e-06, 3.0075821145106816e-06, 6.713527085725027e-06, 2.204123915846549e-05, 7.880065404542858e-06, 4.3539870647002475e-05, 6.0898558226633984e-05, 7.956054903697144e-05, 4.80968670903199e-05, 3.476307626484116e-05, 3.233622280581405e-05, 4.097520999795124e-05, 1.6048981491512094e-05, 3.4725910431663494e-05, 2.3840743831207534e-05, 4.194630872483221e-05, 3.472531193096608e-05, 2.9240209403218155e-05, 2.5871727972711297e-05, 1.1918039641386187e-05, 1.2189485552920143e-05, 8.254477280067191e-06, 5.343416003103456e-06, 0.0, 4.795714549478586e-06, 6.705621859254362e-06, 9.484831383410081e-06, 2.503719812292549e-05, 1.9037212038371403e-05, 2.448114104715256e-05, 3.2063674685728836e-05, 2.73499598297465e-05, 2.6255716088190032e-05, 2.930473870366029e-05, 2.490020970307041e-05, 2.4037259675477766e-05, 1.8683888229243836e-05, 9.573344744760269e-06, 2.01589736663327e-05, 2.8955116521484698e-05, 1.934869527601605e-05, 2.1111566182648825e-05, 1.0035410663340645e-05, 4.154485944681635e-06, 8.468739061212046e-06, 8.415088253238056e-06, 1.3883239181832948e-06, 0.0, 2.9995080806747692e-06, 1.6303266848611124e-06, 3.714448088730736e-06, 8.976418947425114e-06, 9.729566693747293e-06, 3.3588780313874236e-05, 1.7154466165266127e-05, 1.9646193877372823e-05, 9.475852684603824e-06, 9.763432041631274e-06, 2.5840349706066022e-05, 1.4272109443725072e-05, 2.262309793162043e-05, 1.733067926359468e-05, 8.405046389852468e-06, 1.6489619195801272e-05, 6.6721749177376435e-06, 5.2645543870584616e-06, 5.563468043439559e-06, 5.668953522517651e-06, 2.564151874715539e-06, 4.72535638047152e-06, 1.1322053548784465e-06, 4.683593955822e-06, 5.170243182388084e-06, 1.4458242427134072e-06, 5.110793484760465e-06, 8.06295555698897e-06, 1.7613618850094893e-05, 1.3702227753862316e-05, 1.2582942563061514e-05, 1.5863866870429223e-05, 5.763738591399926e-06, 5.010013765012819e-06, 3.355941190486578e-06, 1.2264709219075303e-05, 3.0533139142568385e-06, 5.2266756983622735e-06, 3.0845411025383717e-06, 7.013177761012944e-06, 1.5042033081191253e-05, 7.918060391926394e-06, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3.0146814988996414e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.4253135689851767e-05, 0.0, 1.4218885523752648e-05, 0.0, 1.539361472861057e-05, 0.0, 3.981789947307646e-05, 0.0, 1.2433017120264575e-05, 1.2777756481516975e-05, 1.2764382267720154e-05, 0.0, 1.2131652695046646e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 1.9324418335008117e-05, 0.0, 5.3279343598486864e-05, 1.316118503310038e-05, 8.202637968370628e-06, 8.606938339893733e-06, 2.2898281255009e-06, 0.0, 3.510274573677153e-06, 1.6317872149471709e-06, 4.578600840631114e-06, 3.877291479264245e-06, 2.8741881616021876e-06, 0.0, 1.0729671296519832e-05, 4.808871405969733e-06, 4.534612698729401e-06, 4.3333188889370365e-06, 0.0, 2.743032696949748e-06, 4.019804235533729e-06, 1.8078426019917002e-06, 5.444991968636846e-06]
```

Each element is the combined signal for an hour and the list is over 24 days. Therefore, should have 24 days * 24 hours = 576 elements.

I am interested in the dynamics of the signal of each term over the course of days. However, confounding to this is the baseline changes of the signal within a day. I also have time series for basic terms that capture this baseline signal during a day such as the following.

```
baseline = [0.0056738537419516195, 0.005420397434626666, 0.005019676698052322, 0.004214006968007205, 0.004143451622795924, 0.00373395198248036, 0.0037080495988714344, 0.0036409523281401525, 0.003919898659196092, 0.004388163261294729, 0.004595501330006892, 0.005097033972892097, 0.0052221285817481335, 0.005184009325081863, 0.005273633551787361, 0.005053393415305126, 0.004444952439008902, 0.004552838940992971, 0.004808237374463801, 0.004895327691624783, 0.005059086256629757, 0.005598114319387153, 0.005952632334681949, 0.005717805004263755, 0.006126432469142252, 0.005592477569387059, 0.004920585487387107, 0.004318038669070883, 0.003877225571288378, 0.0036583898426795327, 0.0037336953886437474, 0.0037760782770061294, 0.0042338376814351954, 0.004192003050341723, 0.0046450557083186645, 0.004900468947653463, 0.005272546953959605, 0.005265723105151999, 0.0052304537716869855, 0.005121826744125637, 0.005224078793461002, 0.00501027352884918, 0.004871995260153345, 0.004863044486978714, 0.005310347911635811, 0.0058606870895965765, 0.00596470801561322, 0.005997180909289017, 0.00588291246890472, 0.005328610690842843, 0.004941976393965633, 0.004426509645673344, 0.0041172533679088375, 0.0038888190559989945, 0.003785501144341545, 0.0038683019610415165, 0.003826474222198437, 0.004178336738982966, 0.004574137078717032, 0.004854291797756379, 0.005216590267890586, 0.00514712218170792, 0.005217487414098377, 0.005239554740422529, 0.005138433888329476, 0.0050591314342241745, 0.005099277335119803, 0.00469742744667216, 0.005140145739820509, 0.005534156237221868, 0.006098190503066302, 0.00627542293362276, 0.005859315099582288, 0.0055863100804189264, 0.005193523620749424, 0.004680401455731111, 0.0041370327176107335, 0.003790198190936078, 0.0037143182477912154, 0.0037406926128218908, 0.0038838040372017974, 0.00413455625482474, 0.004309030576010342, 0.004768381364059312, 0.004905695025592956, 0.0050965947056771715, 0.005178951654634759, 0.005250840996574289, 0.005083679897873849, 0.0050438189257025106, 0.00465730975130931, 0.004511425103430987, 0.004631293617276186, 0.0049417738509291015, 0.005495036992426772, 0.0056409591251836465, 0.005487421237451456, 0.005093572532544252, 0.005043698439924855, 0.004837771685295603, 0.0038251289273366134, 0.003817852658627033, 0.003792612420533331, 0.003922716174790973, 0.00412646233748187, 0.004534488299255124, 0.004712687777471286, 0.005096266809417225, 0.00523394116440575, 0.005257672264041691, 0.005305086574696615, 0.005100654966986151, 0.004965826463906992, 0.005073115958176456, 0.00469441228683261, 0.004553136348768357, 0.004723653823501124, 0.004726168081415059, 0.005290955031631742, 0.005325956759690025, 0.005453676000994151, 0.005531903354394338, 0.005121462750913455, 0.004790546408707061, 0.004460326025284444, 0.003982093750443299, 0.0036151869988949132, 0.0035295702958713982, 0.003722662298606401, 0.004089779292755358, 0.004116707488056058, 0.004463311658604419, 0.004863245054602056, 0.005019950105663084, 0.005111292599872651, 0.0050328244675445916, 0.004886511461492081, 0.005017059119637564, 0.004997550003214928, 0.004989853142609061, 0.004888243576205561, 0.004801721031771264, 0.005142349216675533, 0.0053550501391269115, 0.00510410900976245, 0.005113311675603742, 0.004865951202283446, 0.004739388247627576, 0.004314592960862043, 0.003932197365205607, 0.0036889365827877003, 0.003444247563217489, 0.0033695476656641706, 0.003779678994400599, 0.004182362477080399, 0.004650999598571368, 0.004964528816231351, 0.005246502668776329, 0.005150211093436487, 0.0051813375657147505, 0.005326590813316477, 0.00501407415865325, 0.004920848192186853, 0.005020741681762219, 0.005108871853087233, 0.004991922013198609, 0.005551866678436957, 0.005681472655730911, 0.005624204122058199, 0.005202581478369662, 0.00490495583623749, 0.0043628317352519584, 0.0037568042368143423, 0.0035018559432594323, 0.0035627004864066413, 0.003560172130774401, 0.003604382929642445, 0.003782708492731446, 0.003958167037361377, 0.004405696805281344, 0.004888234197579893, 0.004849378554876764, 0.005035728295111269, 0.005150565049279978, 0.005104177573029002, 0.005540331228404623, 0.005146813504207926, 0.004991504807148932, 0.0050371760815936415, 0.005174258383207836, 0.005598418288045426, 0.0056576481335463774, 0.00561832393839059, 0.005408391628077189, 0.0052292710408241285, 0.004705309149638305, 0.003924934489565002, 0.003854606161156092, 0.0038935040219155712, 0.003830335124052002, 0.003746046574771941, 0.003865490274877053, 0.004168222873979538, 0.0045871293840885514, 0.004915772256778214, 0.005072434696646597, 0.00492522147976003, 0.004978792784547765, 0.004963870334948144, 0.004955409293231536, 0.004709890770618299, 0.004888202349958703, 0.0051805005663287775, 0.005568883603736712, 0.005781789868618008, 0.006061759631832967, 0.005730308168750368, 0.0055273545529884146, 0.005050318950400666, 0.004505314632141857, 0.0041320733921015994, 0.0037557073980650723, 0.0034979193552635043, 0.0037461620721961097, 0.0036352203964434373, 0.003974040173135196, 0.004094756199243869, 0.004649079406159152, 0.004920019940715673, 0.005231951964023264, 0.005121117845618645, 0.005064423379922766, 0.00498326981229982, 0.004871188222923238, 0.004660839287914527, 0.0047034466283560495, 0.004866548640835444, 0.005578880008506938, 0.0059683185805929845, 0.006061498706153822, 0.005800490254423062, 0.0054633509277901724, 0.004921961696040911, 0.004376719066835311, 0.00393610914724284, 0.0037954515471031775, 0.003581690980473693, 0.003563708289302751, 0.0037463007418473766, 0.00403278474399164, 0.004356886520045223, 0.004787462849992179, 0.005179338649547787, 0.005143654461390953, 0.005203417442834235, 0.005153892139635152, 0.005114303176192244, 0.00504646961230832, 0.00478839952880454, 0.004711338394289699, 0.004911682972324793, 0.005442432018950797, 0.005865476365139558, 0.006157467255298909, 0.005776991413458904, 0.00537648513923766, 0.005215877640811999, 0.004586994881879395, 0.00404235177861292, 0.0038098588593210615, 0.003611933103919232, 0.003782482344031445, 0.003847756732676113, 0.004015496451997738, 0.004222327790973872, 0.004767228509347478, 0.005026217727591916, 0.005032992226639765, 0.0051856184936032845, 0.005070660243331873, 0.005025667638424633, 0.004771111450073196, 0.0049169687623427365, 0.0, 0.004725137860724068, 0.00480564403797717, 0.004993865191923319, 0.005382243541508231, 0.005436232552738047, 0.005416886729676188, 0.004777014387860352, 0.0048255785043644925, 0.004081842852408802, 0.004090331218562488, 0.00378104976817826, 0.003521792464859018, 0.0036283065618489215, 0.003818665737661915, 0.003988803567300145, 0.004483523199147563, 0.004696601941747573, 0.005206918843848881, 0.005231253931233336, 0.005154439277447777, 0.005107271378732522, 0.004862372011026066, 0.005097539245443387, 0.004771922511620435, 0.004800155668906229, 0.004886324331150043, 0.005186594367994167, 0.0055550364814704704, 0.00565254113064783, 0.00542892074907446, 0.005216026402108949, 0.0050842262523550985, 0.004506330112231061, 0.004262871158699087, 0.004073705404217544, 0.003562133424289835, 0.003499455612234611, 0.0037587992642927636, 0.004170545895025578, 0.004646029409170125, 0.004941082109950799, 0.005336110809450001, 0.005238846272634943, 0.0051019151317224926, 0.004828998520466023, 0.00470819320853546, 0.004974373055097931, 0.004975308413634935, 0.005266317039295838, 0.005489162450620279, 0.005606273008057806, 0.00603476714807901, 0.0061970275556501725, 0.0058349840239690235, 0.005192678736923442, 0.004639151581343363, 0.004229911816211891, 0.003727661961919841, 0.00375780482393585, 0.0033937487713780225, 0.003400171769633621, 0.003719857252709842, 0.0037474521895174925, 0.004410321140619574, 0.00505109832021614, 0.00506160098731807, 0.005046922423918226, 0.005300710721177051, 0.005104647840739084, 0.004974276083656935, 0.004902745159619985, 0.005039594632444682, 0.005189007878086687, 0.005840559146565768, 0.005924790523904985, 0.006041782063467494, 0.006054874048959406, 0.005728511142370623, 0.005014567400775691, 0.004479858189014036, 0.004064222403658478, 0.0038690888337760544, 0.0038101713160671666, 0.0038192317788082945, 0.003855643888760465, 0.004151893395194348, 0.004439198456142054, 0.004868610511159107, 0.005164087705238066, 0.0052260812748906515, 0.005049306708959293, 0.005295364532855441, 0.004976241631407976, 0.005325257379808529, 0.004981215539676753, 0.004904617253355752, 0.005133080934624669, 0.005474999665809228, 0.006018281474269119, 0.0059556619441451936, 0.00582564335486158, 0.0057773567703702745, 0.005185870554701607, 0.004927387470357575, 0.004290471577704514, 0.003894605250504856, 0.0036579206650162693, 0.0037227880322444513, 0.0037587839308041025, 0.004025131552347727, 0.0043915455477435165, 0.004973183367291931, 0.005602412946227073, 0.005438255876982902, 0.005057281453194344, 0.0055819722968782305, 0.0052582960278547575, 0.0060302188495155494, 0.003969113083640037, 0.004874700151948723, 0.0048366059153241445, 0.005174590517957408, 0.005237240077942745, 0.005935388138900985, 0.006375850801552381, 0.006218749794135666, 0.005833520305137985, 0.005325978611613252, 0.00473056992525788, 0.0039874605990664344, 0.0038460789847597175, 0.003587065463944717, 0.00384212944765237, 0.004264645875837948, 0.004969973892903938, 0.005856983835337711, 0.006181231788159266, 0.006313470979891048, 0.006097287985997557, 0.005694104539336737, 0.005355534257732001, 0.005274420505031954, 0.004712403572544698, 0.004584515000959549, 0.004766412751530095, 0.0048104263193712886, 0.005309031929686986, 0.006042498279882524, 0.006496377367343072, 0.005619222170751848, 0.005418471293122766, 0.005015661629991529, 0.005062499505228742, 0.004308572994534354, 0.0038880894398937347, 0.003538125785331658, 0.0034843298748529253, 0.003774099147478583, 0.003896742470805163, 0.004541861762097922, 0.004553179667775172, 0.004948038015149709, 0.0050269339456022605, 0.00522398911361471, 0.005050975431726277, 0.005007174429180125, 0.004833758244552214, 0.004670604547693902, 0.00477521510651887, 0.004939453753268834, 0.005239435739336397, 0.005820798534429634, 0.006094069145690364, 0.005673509972509797, 0.005375844111251002, 0.005187640280456208, 0.00476628984541101, 0.004247493846603608, 0.003794806926377327, 0.003435122854871529, 0.003587919312587277, 0.003811897320196127, 0.0042459415490763925, 0.00460744683733153, 0.004807733730818607, 0.005155657515164588, 0.005405463068510853, 0.005224147724524333, 0.005351078308428722, 0.005384714635929638, 0.005362056525935763, 0.0051377016971353075, 0.004941059319359612, 0.004966034655341646, 0.005026256144832193, 0.005442607412384369, 0.0059898202401797275, 0.005612531062072142, 0.005603529527930128, 0.0051493731726657554, 0.004544820351700367, 0.004496920773323335, 0.00424357787751253, 0.0036690501594786006, 0.003700340743778253, 0.0038846659058119253, 0.004159671170598417, 0.004794839922729552, 0.005004852590193807, 0.005163099925195087, 0.005645338914676821, 0.005432262412191398, 0.0050802949835114155, 0.005169574505964038, 0.0052347116826927985, 0.0052757424822272225, 0.0056125420409050475, 0.005578375783486106, 0.005944651628427074, 0.006010407699526147, 0.0061534279769882615, 0.005756457061668538, 0.005283251628717022, 0.004694029423550289, 0.0042271372620665245, 0.003995084263772031, 0.003916612465121526, 0.00385882298694225, 0.0039353658124175695, 0.00403048536977438, 0.0039523025458470164, 0.004692943486212761, 0.005099144811322234, 0.005182029052264465, 0.005496327599559573, 0.0053953892408097875, 0.005256712315751134, 0.004628655585945719, 0.005255300089578979, 0.004727544165215228, 0.005365188522646431, 0.006321448616075385, 0.005962859901186893, 0.0064913517773445605, 0.006403310018717368, 0.005985231247570929, 0.005536676822123271, 0.005652983876148263, 0.0053962798830303575, 0.0036360246130896887, 0.0034235996705107084, 0.004421584551524996, 0.003810299791511898, 0.0038131330853627154, 0.0038483466362599773, 0.005120205311426739, 0.0048344210780759, 0.005090949889906456, 0.005557094917028417, 0.005276073619631902, 0.0056143238257037814, 0.005700457782933553, 0.00584351804652435, 0.004893880732421001, 0.005475919992851946, 0.005248580353868141, 0.005350058838515571, 0.006083169087767963, 0.005703392826945841, 0.006319084795547654, 0.005231157508317081, 0.005381213703447174, 0.005027572682644346, 0.0042202572347266884, 0.004068212855323105, 0.003991170422748069, 0.0037477607718658665, 0.004077183917326014, 0.00408925876065761, 0.004650332253801002, 0.004960348232472058, 0.005144796809267916, 0.00597460791635549, 0.005407754333445995, 0.005265714189536858, 0.005391654498789258, 0.00495731680894397, 0.005033086804203971, 0.00511026991441738, 0.005391897414595909, 0.006005653123816428, 0.0066265552258310415]
```

i think that a good way for me to extract out the signal I am interested in would be to do a spectral analysis on the timeseries for my terms. The high frequencies should be the daily patterns which I want to get rid of and the lower frequencies should be what I'm interested in. I want to somehow 'divide' my observed signal for a term by the baseline daily signal.

This is my baseline's original signal
[image: baseline original]
and this is my term's original signal
[image: term's original signal]
and what i'm trying to do is get something like this in a general way without introducing artefacts. i.e remove the ups and downs that happen every day anyway and capture the general trend.
[image: term tranformed]

The naive way I thought of doing this is to first generate ffts for both using numpy(below).

baselines fft
[image: baseline's fft]

term1s fft
[image: term1's fft]

and then create a filter like below

```
fft2 = fft(term1, n=t)
mgft2=abs(fft2)  
plot(mgft2[0:t/2+1])
bp  = fft2[:]
for i in range(len(bp)):
if i>=22:
    bp[i] = 0
ibp = ifft(bp)
```

but from what i understand that introduces artefacts, changes the magnitudes and I am not sure how to pick a cutting point. I was hoping for some guidance with respect to implementation in numpy on a better way to divide out my baseline frequencies from my term's frequencies.
thanks

Comment: You're asking for an FFT tutorial, it seems. Google is a better bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's one thing to give the code, another to give an explanation. If you just want to look at the spectra, try the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hh = np.hanning(len(term1)) # Use a Hann window to deal with spectral leakage
St = np.fft.rfft(hh*term1)
Sb = np.fft.rfft(hh*baseline)

FSample = 1.0/24            # Sampling frequency is 1/24th of a day
deltaF = 1.0/(len(term1)*FSample)  # Frequency resolution is 1/capT = 1/(NumSamples*FSample)

faxis = deltaF*np.arange(len(St))

plt.plot(faxis, np.log10(np.abs(np.array([St, Sb]).T)))
```

[image: Spectra of term1 (blue) and baseline (green)]

See Wikipedia's explanation of [spectral leakage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_leakage) and [windowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) for details on `hh`.  The x-axis of the plot is calibrated in days. There are two thin peaks in the `baseline` spectrum at 1 and 2 day periodicity, and a broad peak around 1 day in the `term1` spectrum.

It wasn't clear to me from your question if the baseline data already had the real data stripped out. If so, I think this shows that there isn't much structure in one that's distinguishable from the other.

Another thing to keep in mind is that Fourier analysis assumes the signal is stationary. Depending on the physics of what you're measuring this assumption may or may not be true. Certainly, the time-domain plot of `term1` doesn't look at all stationary, with a wild change in character starting around day 12:[image: np.plot(np.arange(len(term1))/24.0, term1)]

Having said all that, if you have a way to characterize the baseline data, you might be able to apply noise cancelation algorithms like the [Widrow-Hoff LMS algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter). Wikipedia presents a very theoretical overview, I'm not sure where to find a more practical application oriented explanation.

How did you come up with the `term1`/`baseline` separation in your example data?

Comment: thanks. So the wild change in character of the term1 is exactly what I want to capture. How the overall signal goes up and then goes down across days. What I want to get rid of is the cyclicality (the fact that it goes up and down every day) over the course of a day. Both the baseline and term1 are original data. The difference is that baseline should not show any change in patterns across days (Just look at the first 200 elements, the rest is just a particular error with losing data entirely) and so only captures the up and down during a day.

Comment: Does it make sense to make a low pass filter that makes everything higher than a certain frequency 0 and then use ifft on it get the signal back?

Comment: @msohail: That's exactly what you *can't* do as I tried to describe in my answer.  When you convert back your signal will have aliasing.  Having a cutoff that sharp in the frequency domain would require more samples in the time domain (for the case of a perfectly sharp cutoff it would be infinitely many samples)

Comment: thanks. I think what i'm confused about in your response is that i am thinking that what you meant by a filter (a low pass filter) is that it sets all freqs above some freq to 0 and only lets low freq through. Clearly, I am missing something but could you maybe provide some guidance on how I could implement a filter without going into the frequency domain.

Comment: also, the filter would be one way. But since I do have my baseline data, i used fnumpy.ft to create its fft. I know multiplying/diving in freq domain is adding/subtractin in time domain. But in terms of actual implementation, dividing out the baseline's fft from my terms fft and then taking the inverse does not seem to be what i want. so in terms of implementing in python, knowing the fft of my baseline, how can i adjust my terms signal for it

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying (or dividing) in the frequency domain is equivalent to convolving in the time domain.  In other words a high-pass FIR filter would remove your low-frequency components directly without going into the frequency domain.  If you *do* go to the frequency domain first be aware that simply removing some frequency components and converting back to time will introduce artifacts.  FIR filter design is actually based on choosing filters you *can* multiply by which also meet your desired frequency specs.

All that said, it sounds like you already know the baselines and you could apply your adjustments directly from your known baselines to your data.  The point of filtering would be that it would work *without knowing the baselines*.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both your "baseline signal" and your timeseries data contain information overlapping in spectral content.  As such, an FFT doesn't provide any extra help in removing the overlapping portions that end up in the same FFT frequency bins.

As an FFT is a linear operator, subtracting in the frequency domain isn't any different from subtracting directly in the time domain.